# compilation fatal error boost/filesystem

Tags: linux, debian, xfce

when running **make**

> g++ -pedantic -Wall -W -g `pkg-config --cflags --libs liblog4cxx
>   dbus-c++-1` -DDOUANE_VERSION=\"0.9.0\" -o freedesktop/desktop_file.o
>   -c freedesktop/desktop_file.cpp In file included from freedesktop/desktop_file.cpp:1:0: freedesktop/desktop_file.h:5:37:
>   fatal error: boost/filesystem/path.hpp: No such file or directory
>   compilation terminated. Makefile:36: recipe for target
>   'freedesktop/desktop_file.o' failed make: ***
>   [freedesktop/desktop_file.o] Error 1

getting this, Im on a distro with XFCE environment, as I searched the freedesktop/desktop_file.cpp has to do with the XFCE. But the main problem is line

> boost/filesystem/path.hpp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Boost "no such file or directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12241152/608639)

Answer (score 0):

the solution given by https://stackoverflow.com/a/25770596/1320686

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-dev
```