# Cannot build C++ source (due to libraries?)

Tags: c++, windows, rcpp

To see how C++ works in order to solve differential equations, I tried the following script found in a tutorial in internet. It should work.

I don't directly use C++. I use R and Rcpp library to compile/run the script. Here is the script:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace std;
using namespace boost::numeric::odeint;


/* we solve the simple ODE x' = 3/(2t^2) + x/(2t)
* with initial condition x(1) = 0.
* Analytic solution is x(t) = sqrt(t) - 1/t
*/

void rhs( const double x , double &dxdt , const double t )
{
  dxdt = 3.0/(2.0*t*t) + x/(2.0*t);
}

void write_cout( const double &x , const double t )
{
  cout << t << '\t' << x << endl;
}

// state_type = double
typedef runge_kutta_dopri5< double > stepper_type;

int main()
{
  double x = 0.0;    
  integrate_adaptive( make_controlled( 1E-12 , 1E-12 , stepper_type () ) ,rhs , x , 1.0 , 10.0 , 0.1 , write_cout );
 }
```

The following error appeared:

```
ex1.cpp:2:36: fatal error: boost/numeric/odeint.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>
                                    ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [ex1.o] Error 1
```

Should I download/load a library before running my script? How can do it?

**EDIT:**
I'm working with Windows and I already installed Rtools. I'm really new with Rcpp. What I want to know is whether I have to install something, like boost library, and where I should install it.

Comment: Look like you don't have the boost libraries installed. See https://www.boost.org

Comment: This is a compilation error not a linkage error. Boost numeric a pure header library.

Comment: It means when the compiler tries to compile your program (i.e. ex1.cpp), it found `#include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>` at line number `2`. What it does is, after searching for the file (i.e. `odeint.hpp`), it couldn't find it in the specified location. So, you need to get the file and put it in the right location.

Comment: @Love Coding. Right, it couldn't find the odeint.hpp file. How do I know what the right location is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have *multiple* critical errors:

- you want to call this from R, yet no Rcpp interface
- code you call from R cannot have a `main()`
- no Boost headers: you need the [BH](https://cran.r-project.org/package=BH) package installed

Corrected code below.

#### Code

This version of your code works and runs the example. I added a few comments in it.

```
// include Rcpp, it takes care of most other headers you need
#include <Rcpp.h>

// include Boost's odeint
#include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>

// tell R you need Boost
// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace std;
using namespace boost::numeric::odeint;


/* we solve the simple ODE x' = 3/(2t^2) + x/(2t)
* with initial condition x(1) = 0.
* Analytic solution is x(t) = sqrt(t) - 1/t
*/

void rhs( const double x , double &dxdt , const double t ) {
  dxdt = 3.0/(2.0*t*t) + x/(2.0*t);
}

void write_cout( const double &x , const double t ) {
  // use Rcpp's stream
  Rcpp::Rcout << t << '\t' << x << endl;
}

// state_type = double
typedef runge_kutta_dopri5< double > stepper_type;

// call this from R
// [[Rcpp::export]]
bool boostExample() {
  double x = 0.0;    
  integrate_adaptive(make_controlled( 1E-12 , 1E-12 , stepper_type () ) ,
                     rhs , x , 1.0 , 10.0 , 0.1 , write_cout );
  return true;
}

/*** R
boostExample()                  // call from R
*/
```

#### Demo

Because of the R snippet at the end, running `sourceCpp()` on this to compile, link, load also runs the new `boostExample()` function:

```
R> sourceCpp("/tmp/sobh.cpp")

R> boostExample()                  
1   0
1.00843 0.0125618
1.0197  0.0291282
1.03098 0.0454238
1.04226 0.061457
1.05409 0.0779974
1.06591 0.0942666
1.07774 0.110273
1.09015 0.126803
1.10257 0.14306
1.11498 0.159055
1.12802 0.175574
1.14106 0.191821
1.15409 0.207804
1.16778 0.224315
1.18147 0.240553
1.19516 0.256527
1.20954 0.273032
1.22392 0.289264
1.2383  0.305233
1.25341 0.321735
1.26852 0.337966
1.28414 0.354468
1.29976 0.370699
1.31591 0.387205
1.33207 0.403439
1.34877 0.419952
1.36548 0.436192
1.38276 0.452714
1.40004 0.468964
1.41791 0.485498
1.43579 0.501761
1.45428 0.518311
1.47278 0.534589
1.49191 0.551159
1.51105 0.567457
1.53086 0.58405
1.55067 0.600373
1.57117 0.616993
1.59167 0.633343
1.6129  0.649996
1.63412 0.666378
1.6561  0.683067
1.67808 0.699487
1.70084 0.716217
1.7236  0.732678
1.74718 0.749455
1.77075 0.765963
1.79517 0.782792
1.8196  0.799352
1.8449  0.816238
1.87021 0.832857
1.89643 0.849806
1.92266 0.866487
1.94984 0.883505
1.97702 0.900256
2.0052  0.91735
2.03338 0.934176
2.0626  0.951351
2.09182 0.96826
2.12212 0.985523
2.15242 1.00252
2.18385 1.01988
2.21528 1.03697
2.24789 1.05443
2.28049 1.07163
2.31432 1.0892
2.34816 1.1065
2.38327 1.12419
2.41838 1.14161
2.45482 1.15943
2.49127 1.17697
2.5291  1.19492
2.56694 1.2126
2.60622 1.23068
2.64551 1.2485
2.68631 1.26674
2.72711 1.28471
2.7695  1.3031
2.81188 1.32123
2.85591 1.33979
2.89994 1.35809
2.9457  1.37682
2.99145 1.39529
3.039   1.41422
3.08655 1.43287
3.13598 1.45199
3.18541 1.47084
3.23679 1.49016
3.28818 1.50921
3.34162 1.52875
3.39505 1.54802
3.45062 1.56778
3.50619 1.58727
3.56399 1.60727
3.6218  1.627
3.68193 1.64724
3.74206 1.66721
3.80463 1.68771
3.8672  1.70794
3.93231 1.7287
3.99743 1.7492
4.0652  1.77024
4.13297 1.79101
4.20352 1.81235
4.27406 1.83341
4.34751 1.85505
4.42096 1.87641
4.49744 1.89837
4.57392 1.92004
4.65356 1.94232
4.7332  1.96432
4.81615 1.98694
4.89911 2.00927
4.98551 2.03225
5.07192 2.05493
5.16194 2.07826
5.25196 2.10131
5.34575 2.12502
5.43953 2.14844
5.53726 2.17254
5.63499 2.19635
5.73684 2.22086
5.83868 2.24507
5.94483 2.26999
6.05097 2.29461
6.16161 2.31996
6.27224 2.34501
6.38757 2.37081
6.50289 2.3963
6.62311 2.42255
6.74334 2.4485
6.86867 2.47523
6.99401 2.50164
7.12469 2.52885
7.25537 2.55575
7.39162 2.58347
7.52788 2.61086
7.66995 2.63909
7.81203 2.66699
7.96018 2.69575
8.10834 2.72418
8.26284 2.75349
8.41733 2.78246
8.57845 2.81233
8.73957 2.84185
8.9076  2.8723
9.07562 2.90239
9.25086 2.93342
9.4261  2.96411
9.60886 2.99575
9.79162 3.02703
9.98222 3.05929
10  3.06228
[1] TRUE
R>
```

Comment: Thanks Dirk. My script still doesn't work. Here the error message :fatal error: boost/numeric/odeint.hpp: No such file or directory. So I guess I should install the C++ library called boost, right?

Comment: I said you need to install [the CRAN package BH](https://cran.r-project.org/package=BH) and provided you with a link.  Ie do `install.packages("BH")` to install this R package, just as you did with Rcpp.

Comment: I did install the BH package, but the error still appeared.

Comment: Then you are doing something else wrong. I showed you a working and worked example.  BH works on Windows, and is tested by CRAN.

Comment: I think there was a typo in your example. I put "// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]" instead of "/// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]" and it works. Is it right?

Comment: Good catch. That is a typo, indeed. (Which does not matter for me on Ubuntu as I have Boost in another location.)  You need the two `//` as you said.  Will edit my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Please install boost headers. This is not a library issue.

Either use a package manager* or download boost from boost.org unpack and add header directory `<boost-location>/boost` to your include directories `-I`.

* F.e. On Ubuntu f.e. `sudo apt -y install libboost1.65-dev`

Anthony Hauser, forget the down votes. Try my suggestion, you'll be alright.

Say you unpacked it to /home/anthony/include then add -I /home/anthony/include/boost-1.65 or on Windows C:\Users\Anthony\Boost add -I C:\Users\Anthony\Boost\boost-1.65

Comment: Could someone explain the downvote? What is wrong with folks?

Comment: This is a premature answer. We haven’t clarified the issue completely, we don’t know OP’s OS, for example. (And if it’s Ubuntu, we have [a duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12241152/boost-no-such-file-or-directory) already.) Your generic answer is nothing more useful than an [existing comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49994949/cannot-build-c-source-due-to-libraries#comment87006757_49994949).

Comment: Crazy. The comments are wrong. You don't need to install libraries for odeint.h. It is purely a header only part of boost. If he takes my suggestion, he is done within minutes. The thing is that there are a couple of complicated folks out there that really have an issue with the world. Geez!

Comment: Running `apt install libboost1.65-dev` _is_ installing a library.

Comment: Sigh. It does not install a single shared/static library. There is also no linking involved. But keep it up mate.

Comment: @KavehVahedipour a library does not need to be compiled code.  It can just be header files like a large proportion of Boost.  Library is being used here as a generic term meaning "some packaged routines for you to use".

Comment: @RichardCritten Agreed. I have written and used header only libraries myself. The point is that my suggestion gets the guy going and some unhappy folks come in and downvote a *solution* for technicalities. When you speak of libraries to c++ beginners they start  getting all excited about LD_FLAGS and such.

Comment: @Kaveh: Thanks for your answer. I downloaded the boost library, unpacked it but I don't know where to save it. You mentionned that I should "add header directory <boost-location>/boost to your include directories -I". What does this mean for a beginner like me ?

Comment: What system are you on? You may unpack anywhere you desire. In your home directory or a system directory like /usr/local/include etc. Say you unpacked it to /home/anthony/include then add `-I /home/anthony/include/boost-1.65` or on Windows C:\Users\Anthony\Boost add `-I C:\Users\Anthony\Boost\boost-1.65` I updated the answer.

Comment: @Kaveh: Sorry, my question was more: what does "add -I C:\Users\...." mean? Is it something I should do in my .cpp script?

Comment: Add `-I` to the compiler flags. So you are on Windows? Do you build in the command shell or inside Visual Studio?

Comment: I'm in Windows. As I use Rcpp package, I compiled my script directly in R.

Comment: Type the comment here and we should be able to quickly fix it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169664/discussion-between-kaveh-vahedipour-and-anthony-hauser).